# How to create a PNG file from scratch in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, png

To better understand the PNG file format I'm attempting to author a PNG from scratch. My code below gets pretty close, but it's still not correct enough to generate an openable PNG. What am I missing?

```
var fileStart: [UInt8] = [137, 80, 78, 71, 13, 10, 26, 10]
var header: [UInt8] = [2, 2, 8, 2, 1, 1, 1]
var backgroundHeader: [UInt8] = [98, 75, 71, 68]
var backgroundColor: [UInt8] = [2, 2, 2]
var imageDataStart: [UInt8] = [73, 68, 65, 84]
var imageData: [UInt8] = [0, 0, 0,
                            0, 0, 0,
                            0, 0, 0,
                            0, 0, 0]
var end: [UInt8] = [73, 69, 78, 68, 174, 66, 96, 130]

var bytes = fileStart + header + backgroundHeader + backgroundColor
bytes = bytes + imageDataStart + imageData + end

let data = NSData(bytes: bytes, length: bytes.count * sizeof(UInt8))
let img = UIImage(data: data)
```

Output data:

```
<89504e47 0d0a1a0a 02020802 01010162
 4b474402 02024944 41540000 00000000
 00000000 00004945 4e44ae42 6082>
```

PNG data generated from UIKit libraries:

```
<89504e47 0d0a1a0a 0000000d 49484452
 00000002 00000002 08020000 00fdd49a
 73000000 01735247 4200aece 1ce90000
 001c6944 4f540000 00020000 00000000
 00010000 00280000 00010000 00010000
 0040e06c 00350000 000c4944 41541819
 62600003 00000000 ffff93ac dac80000
 00094944 41546360 00030000 0e0001ef
 38c3bb00 00000049 454e44ae 426082>
```

Comment: To start, the header is wrong, it should be an IHDR chunk, and the width/height are 4-byte long each.